# Does Google TV's (or more generally Android's) HLS player support alternative audio?

Tags: android, ios5, http-live-streaming, google-tv

Does Google TV's (or more generally Android's) HLS player support alternative audio? See page 27 of [the HLS IETF draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-07). I can see the [support for that in iOS 5](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2288/_index.html) already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently - We did announce (at Google I/O) some API's that are Google TV specific that will be available in an upcoming release.

Comment: Hi Les, Thanks for comments - does that mean the alternative audio will be Google TV specific and it will not come on tablets/smartphones? Can you share some slides/timelines about the GoogleTV plans announced on Google I/O?

Comment: Much of what we announced at I/O for the "next release" was announced officially today 11/14/12 and started rolling out to customers for LG TV's.  Other OEM's will be at a later time.

Comment: Any good developers summary, what is new on Google TV? Any reason why LG was selected? What about Sony and Vizio???

Comment: LG was first to get it done.  MPEG-DASH support, Playready/SmoothStreaming, MediaDevices, a few more, if you watch the I/O presentation, the only thing that I know didn't make it was MediaDevices.